# Can't get 21:9 to work with

Tags: 18.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I got a LG 34UM69G-B 21:9 monitor today, I've had one hell of a time getting it working. I still have not gotten 21:9 to work consistently. I have gotten it to work once but upon reboot failed and I can't seem to repeat the steps and have it work. Same exact commands (history). I did this with xrandr which everyone online says I should be doing.

I saw something about Nvidia drivers and I'm using Intel (specs below). Not sure if there are some intel drivers that would solve my problem or not. I'm hoping someone here might know how I can solve this so I don't have to return the monitor.

Ubuntu desktop version: 18.04.2 LTS

Monitor: LG 34UM69G-B

Computer: X1 Carbon 6th gen

GPU: Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)

CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8

USB-C dock: pluggable 3 monitor usb-c docking station

Comment: Are you connecting the monitor via the USB-C dock, or via direct DisplayPort/HDMI connection?

Comment: @dobey I have it connected via the dock though connecting directly to the laptop doesn't help